# Do all antiquarks carry and anti-color charge, or can they carry RGB color charges as well?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, antimatter, quarks

I know there are antiquarks with anticolor charges. Are there also antiquarks that instead carry color charges?

Basically, which of these lists describes the types of quarks that there are:

**List one:**

- +2/3 with color charge
- +1/3 with anticolor charge
- -1/3 with color charge
- -2/3 with anticolor charge

**List two:**

- +2/3 with color charge
- +2/3 with anticolor charge
- +1/3 with color charge
- +1/3 with anticolor charge
- -1/3 with color charge
- -1/3 with anticolor charge
- -2/3 with color charge
- -2/3 with anticolor charge

Comment: Yes, antiquarks have anti-colour charges. Gluons have both colour and anti-colour charge. Spin is important.

Comment: relevant answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/770489/

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Sorry, I worded it poorly. I know that there are antiquarks with anticolor. My question was meant to be "are there antiquarks that have RGB color charges RATHER THAN anti-RGB? Or are all antiquarks "anti" in BOTH electromagnetic AND color charges?

Comment: Quarks and antiquarks also have opposite weak isospin, and opposite baryon number, and probably other quantum numbers that I’m not remembering.

Comment: Then your question is very different from what is written. You should edit the question to make it clear that you are asking this instead of that.

Comment: List one is correct. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Strong_interaction_and_color_charge) states, “Every quark carries a color, while every antiquark carries an anticolor.” If quarks could also carry anticolor, and vice versa, this would have been mentioned, because otherwise the quotes statement would be highly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Antiquarks always carry anti-color charges, not the RGB color charges associated with quarks. Therefore, list one is correct:

- Quarks have RGB color charges with electric charges of +2/3 or -1/3.
- Antiquarks have anti-RGB (anti-red, anti-green, anti-blue) color charges with electric charges of -2/3 or +1/3.

No antiquarks carry the RGB color charges of quarks; they are distinct in carrying anti-color charges. This ensures particles are color-neutral!